# Laravel Route group is not clickable in PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm for my Laravel projects. And I'm using Laravel IDE Helper and Laravel Plugin.

```
Route::get('logout', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@logout', 'as' => 'logout']);
```

When you can <kbd>Shift + Click</kbd> to `{{ route('logout') }}` in below.

```
<li><a href="{{ route('logout') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>{{ trans('auth.logout') }}</a></li>
```

But I use Route group like below. It is not clickable

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as'=> 'admin::','middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/', [
       'uses' => 'Admin\HomeController@index',
       'as'   => 'home',
    ]);
});
```

I cannot click `{{ route('admin::home') }}`

```
<li><a href="{{ route('admin::home') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Admin Paneli</a></li>
```

Is there any solution for it ?

Comment: Isn't the name of your route still `home`, not `admin::home` since you have `'as' => 'home',`? That's how I've always done it

Comment: admin::home is different